# rake assets:precompile without database connection and with dynamic routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, apartment-gem

I'm trying to compile my assets for production, this is not done locally.

I've got 2 constraints:

- I cannot connect to the database (for this step)
- I have a dynamic route that usually require to get info from the db (but it's not necessary for the assets compiling)

Basically I run on a docker image that is build outside the production environment. I cannot connect the db. I was using a trick by passing a false db address with an env_var directly in the dockerfile.

But now I have a dynamic route:

```
scope path: ":tenant", constraints: {tenant: Apartment.tenant_names.join('|')}  do
  .... 
end
```

This is working because I reload the routes when a new tenant name is added.

But when I have to compile the assets it failed because the compilation init the app and the routes tried to do `Apartment.tenant_names.join('|')` which will obviously failed without the db connection.

If I replace `Apartment.tenant_names.join('|')`by a string, the db is not called and the compilation runs fine.

Is there something I can use to see if compiling step is trying to init the app and make a condition to do something like:

```
if assets_are_compiling?
   scope path: ":tenant", constraints: {tenant: "assets_compiling"}  do
   ....
else
  scope path: ":tenant", constraints: {tenant: Apartment.tenant_names.join('|')}  do
  .... 
end
```

Any idea ?

**EDIT**: workaround

It's not a solution to the question but here is a workaround for future reference. Apparently using a lambda didn't trigger the compilation error:

```
scope path: ":tenant", constraints: lambda {|request| (Apartment.tenant_names.include?(request.path.split('/')[1])) } do
```

Comment: Whats the whole purpose of defining the routes dynamically in that way? It seems to me that you are doing something like vanity routes very wrong.

Comment: I know that dynamic element in routes.rb is not the "rails way". It's more a question about is this possible or not. Why I'm asking this is because of a multitenant app working without subdomains. I don't want the requests that are not tenant related to fall in the public shema. That's why my constraint is useful so I can grab the non related tenant request and route them properly. I will open an issue on Apartment Github.

Comment: @max I set a workaround that resolve the error, It's cleaner for the routes.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but you might need to tweak the regular expression so that other tasks don't trigger a false positive.

```
if caller.to_s.match(/\/bin\/rake:\d+/) and caller.to_s.match(/\/lib\/sprockets\/rails\/task\.rb:\d+/)
   scope path: ":tenant", constraints: {tenant: "assets_compiling"}  do
     ...
   end
else
  scope path: ":tenant", constraints: {tenant: Apartment.tenant_names.join('|')}  do
    ...
  end
end
```

This code is basically doing a stack trace to see if it was called from `rake assets:precompile`.  But like I said, you might need to tweak the regex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll test it as soon as possible!

Comment: caller.to_s return too many elements, filtering them to get the precompile:assets without false positive will be hard. I'll keep this in mind for the moment.